# The Square Of A Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. The square of $G$ is a graph $G^2$ on $V(G)$ where $vw$ is an edge in $G^2$ iff $d(v,w)=1$ or $d(v,w)=2$ in $G$.

What if we don't want the distance $1$ part? What do we call the graph where $vw$ is an edge iff $d(v,w)=2$?

Comment: Does it necessarily have to have a given name?  I didn't name the leaves I swept off my porch...

Comment: If $G$ is bipartite, then the distance-2 graph square has two disconnected parts induced by the bipartition of $G$, and each of them is called a [half-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_half) of $G$. But this does not answer the non-bipartite case.